# JS check control works in Chrome, not working in IE and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

**HTML:**

```
<input id='sessionCreate' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no' type='checkbox'>
<label for='sessionCreate' data-on='Yes' data-off='No'></label>
```

**JS:**

```
if(!$('#sessionCreate').is(':checked')){
            document.getElementById('step-3').remove();
            document.getElementById('colDiv3').remove();}
```

It works in Chrome but in Mozilla and IE, it does not work.

Comment: What is not working? here checkbox working http://jsfiddle.net/7tqtqLsr/.

Comment: When is the `if` statement executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have elements with IDs `step-3` and `colDiv3`, you could do the following since you seem to use `jQuery` anyway.

```
if( !$('#sessionCreate').is(':checked') ) {
    $('#step-3').remove();
    $('#colDiv3').remove();
}
```

I guess you were after `removeChild` but that would work only if the element to be removed has a parentNode, like below:

```
element = document.getElementById('step-3');
element.parentNode && element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Browser support for `.remove`:

[image]

Comment: [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) works as well.

Comment: @Xufox sure, but it works in WebKit and Firefox, but not IE AFAIK.

Comment: @Xufox yes, it should work on FF as long as the browser version is >= 23.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem in both browsers. Safari too.